# How are daemon threads useful in Python 3.5.1?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, daemon

While going through the python docs for thread objects it had a note on daemon threads wherein it said:

> Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.

So why do we use them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python tries to join non-daemon threads at exit. If you haven't implemented a mechanism to terminate them, python will hang. Annoyingly, ctrl-C typically doesn't work and you have to kill the program externally.

Comment: And presumably, as the name suggests, they're what you'd use if you were writing a daemon for an operating system in Python. That way your machine is guaranteed to not lock up waiting for the daemon to exit when it's shutdown.

Comment: But what about the resources? Since it's written they may not be released properly.